# Best practice for frequent sending webSocket/Socketio/webRCT data

Tags: physics, networking, box2d

I already done game template for classic platformer. I use matter.js for physics and my own override draw functions. Everything works fine. Next stage is to make it multiplayer.

I interest is it good to send user input (force vector) only when play act with keyboard/mouse (apply force on remote gameplay) or to send on every change (for example) absolute x,y and then use set position method.

- GamePLay is fully scaleable (In any resolution same diametric transformation).
- webRTC look like best solution for communication in fly.

I worry about collisions moments.

Any suggest for this question ?

Comment: What issues do you foresee with each of these methods, and why can't you make up your mind? Keep in mind that open "what technology to use" questions are off-topic, and so the question should be steered toward getting help fixing a specific issue.

Comment: Have you tried it? What problems did you run into? [Possibly duplicate existing question, about making a physics-based game multiplayer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6645/lag-compensation-with-networked-2d-games).

Comment: I guest it is a duplicate. I needed right link. Looks like server must make decides to be finally.

Comment: Not yet, take a look at : https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/visual-ts-game-engine