# how do I make flash mmorpg?

Tags: mmo

I want to make games like this.

http://www.fantasy-mmorpg.com/

simple 2d graphics but using Red Dwarf server on the background.

what flash game engine should I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be under the opinion that an engine will allow you to make an MMORPG straight away. [Read this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90/why-is-it-so-hard-to-develop-a-mmo), and rethink your idea.

You could probably use Flixel or FlashPunk for the engine itself. Then have fun spending a few years dealing with the networking and all the content you need.