# multi-thread in mmorpg server

Tags: mmo, server, multithreading

For MMORPG, there is a tick function to update every object's state in a map. The function was triggered by a timer in fixed interval. So each map's update can be dispatch to different thread. At other side, server handle player incoming package have its own threads also: I/O threads. Generally, the handler of the corresponding incoming package run in I/O threads. So there is a problem: thread synchronization. I have consider two methods:

1. Synchronize with mutex. I/O thread lock a mutex before execute handler function and map thread lock same mutex before it execute map's update.
2. Execute all handler functions in map's thread, I/O thread only queue the incoming handler and let map thread to pop the queue then call handler function.

These two have a disadvantage: delay. For method 1, if the map's tick function is running, then all clients' request need to waiting the lock release. For method 2, if map's tick function is running, all clients' request need to waiting for next tick to be handle.

Of course, there is another method: add lock to functions that use data which will be accessed both in I/O thread & map thread. But this is hard to maintain and easy to goes incorrect. It needs carefully check all variables whether or not accessed by both two kinds thread.

My problem is: is there better way to do this? Or from practical view, the delay can be accepted because nothing will happen between 2 tick (the world is driven by continuous tick, all object will paused in 2 tick's interval) Generally, the interval is about 50ms to 100ms

Notice that I said map is logic concept means no interactions can happen between two map except transport. I/O thread means thread in 3rd part network lib which used to handle client request.

Comment: This is probably a premature optimisation. Have you considered using a single-threaded server?

Comment: single thread only support hundreds people. for commercial purpose, it needs thousands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have consider two methods:
>   Synchronize with mutex. I/O thread lock a mutex before execute handler function and map thread lock same mutex before it execute map's update.

If you do this, then there is hardly any point having separate threads, because only one runs at a time!

> Execute all handler functions in map's thread, I/O thread only queue the incoming handler and let map thread to pop the queue then call handler function.

This seems closer to what you should do. The I/O thread should handle I/O - nothing more. It needs to be able to get exclusive access to the message queue or data buffers that let the network exchange data with the game, and that's all.

You would not have 1 single lock for your entire map. Each client has its own lock (or locks), guarding its input and output. Only when that client is sending data or receiving it would you need to lock it.

> Of course, there is another method: add lock to functions that use data which will be accessed both in I/O thread & map thread. But this is hard to maintain and easy to goes incorrect. It needs carefully check all variables whether or not accessed by both two kinds thread.

This is not actually difficult at all. The answer is to make the shared data as small as possible. For example, use 2 queues, one for messages coming in (network -> server) and one for messages going out (server -> network). Lock the queue to add or remove messages, and ensure there is no other data shared across the I/O and logic sections.

Comment: In fact, my method 1 & 2 is almost same: all event handler of all clients and map's tick function are executed sequentially. Use queue still can not make then to be concurrent. In method 2, the map's tick function work like this: for each session do (for all message in queue do (execute logic which the message demand)) do tick function' update job. The consequence is same: no concurrent. Method 2 better at: it will not block I/O thread and have not overhead of mutex lock because one map's tick function always run in its own dedicated thread.

Comment: My method 3 can be viewed as improved method 2. It only add lock need to rather than method 2, it lock a "shared lock" whatever there need a thread synchronization or not. For example, a client message arrived, server need to set player's variable 'a' to 10. But this 'a' never accessed by map's tick function, so 'a' don't need to synchronize, then method 3 can save a lock. Notice that "a=10" is running in I/O thread. You said: "The I/O thread should handle I/O - nothing more", I agree that. But nowadays network lib supply this ability: dispatch job to I/O threads such as boost::asio, netty

Comment: If use method 2, then I/O thread only handle I/O. If use method 1 or 3, then its I/O thread will be used to run business logic job and have to consider thread synchronization problem: a share lock(method 1) or finer granularity locks(method 3)

Comment: You don't usually want to run a game's "business logic" concurrently anyway because that is difficult to make correct. You certainly wouldn't want to do it using the networking library's threading system. Use the I/O library to get a queue of messages and handle them sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an architecture you might want to consider:

You might want to use separate processes for these tasks:
- User authentication
- Realm selection
- Each realm (maybe broken into independent maps)
- Ingame subtasks, such as mail/global chat subsystem, item/npc cache, largely independent of other state, that does not need to further burden the map server.

Using different processes ensures that a faulty module won't bring down the whole system. Partial reboot's and hot swapping's inherently supported. It's easier to scalate this model to several different machines if your needs require it.

Each module's internal architecture's very similar: Your input threads just push messages into a queue. Your core module requests this list each update, and feeds its messages to the message consumers. These message consumers run the required actions through transactions - acquire locks on affected objects (player inventory, pickable item), run actions (pick item), free locks. Outbound messages are queued in a message consumer local queue, so no synchronization's required here. Once all incoming messages have been processed, these thread local queues are harvested, merged and its messages forwarded to their respective targets.

Comment: how is that helping? Maybe I got it wrong but he asked for something completely different. (maybe the last part is somewhat helpful)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explicitly state it. If you're receiving your login and your game/chat/etc messages in the same process, you're either locking the unique queue for each incoming message and then demultiplexing, or you're running separate incoming message queues for each role, further justifying the separation into processes.

Comment: The other functionality you mention definitely run in process respectively. So you prefer synchronize with queue. My worried thing is: does this involve delay that can feel by player? For example: player push a key send a attack command to server, when server receive this, it will not handle this immediately. It need wait for next tick of map, then the command will be executed. The largest delay is almost double interval of ticks. Plus network delay (generally less than 200ms), does it OK?

Answer (score 1):

You can run your IO on background threads that just waits for a full wellformed packet to come in, and then puts the data in the packet into a queue for the main processing thread to process.  The main thread can run in a small while loop like:

```
while(!shutdown)
{
    dequeue_player_input();
    process_objects();
}
```

In general a multi-process instead of a multi-thread approach will better suit an MMO design.  On MMO's I've worked on, a single process could handle anything from the entire world to a 20x20 meter square of the world.  And as player and NPC concentration increased, the server would spin up other processes to handle smaller and smaller pieces of the world.  IE: Maybe we'd start with 100 processes spread over 15 machines for the world, then 5000 players would come to see an event in one spot.  That one spot alone would be handled by 16  processes none of them guaranteed to be on any single machine.

Comment: Your first paragraph and example is what I was recommending: but I don't think I was clear enough.

Comment: Multi-process(single machine or cluster) has a big problem: how to communicate with each other? Single machine's multi-process communication is more complex than multi-thread, need to use mapped-memory or signal or something else. Cluster's multi-process is a impossible mission to do communication, let alone the speed is much slower(1Gbps Ethernet vs memory), how to guarantee the 'happen-before' is extremely difficult(If two machine want to set variable 'a', first machine 1 set 'a' to 1, then machine 2 set 'a' to 'a'+1. You need to guarantee the execution order and feedback result to machines)

Comment: Yes and?  There's a reason why MMOs are the hardest problem in computer science.  See: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90/why-is-it-so-hard-to-develop-a-mmo/1031#1031  Every MMO I've worked on has to solve these type of problems every day.  The answer to your question though is you don't solve that problem you bypass it.  One process is authoritative for an object, all other edge processes have a slightly delayed read-only observation of the object.  Then the difficulty comes in crossing server boundaries and handing off who is authoritative to the next server.

Comment: I can't understand your solution, but I insist it is impossible, at least in a commercial product. Don't like other app like search engine, the time of data synchronization is not important, so it can have a large cluster. But MMO does not. If the time used to synchronize data between machine is long, it can not be accepted(delay), as you can imagine, the data needs to synchronized is big(every player, npc... on the map). And there is another problem: who's data in charge? Machine 1 set a=10, machine 2 set a=9.

Comment: Of course you can put all data needs share on single machine, use IPC or something else to access the map machine, but the speed will be very slow and programming model have a big change, for at least 100k code line project, it is heavy to afford this. I never heard there is a MMO work that this except some experimental project like reddwarf

Comment: Read http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131357/distributing_object_state_for_.php?print=1 it was written by the Technical Director of the MMO I described above.  It's not impossible, I've been on multiple teams that have done it.  Also, for even the smallest MMO you're off by an order of magnitude at 100kLOC.  MXO was 2 million, ENB was 1.6 I think, Agency when I left was ~1.2.

Comment: I read it but there is no magic thing. "Object View" just is proxy pattern in design pattern, distributed object has product many years ago such as CORBA. My doubt comes from two way, one is practical: if some one made it, why there is no any MMO product that can support 'single world'? EVE is single world but has restriction: it map has limitation of player number. Other one is technical: when multi-machine access one shared object, how to make the write-operation is sequential?

Comment: This is same as thread-safe problem: write can not happen concurrent. If the write operation must be sequential, how to utilize the CPUs on this machine? Don't forget machine in a cluster still has more than one CPU. Multi-thread still is a problem. Distributed compute can not slove any demand, area that  highly interacted is improper split into more than one physical machine, the data needs to synchronization is huge, much bigger than 2^n, it is n!. If two area's object will never interact, these two area can put on two physical machine, that's the way EVE approach 'single world' so called

Comment: Go back and read what I said.  There is an authoritative server for every object.  There's no concurrent writing.  Every write takes place on the server that owns the object.  Also the data syncronization is N not 2^N or even N!.  Object on process A that is responsible for the square from 0,0 to 0,20 sends data only to those processes that A) share a common border and B) are within range of that object.  In the case above if an object was more than 20 meters from the border it wasn't replicated to the remote machine.  In practice replication only happened to at most 2 processes.

Comment: Also you're mistaking game design for technical.  Why doesn't World of Warcraft have all 10 million players in the same world?  Could you imagine trying to gain xp in the non-instanced world if that was the case?

Comment: Indeed, put all object which needs share into one physical machine can make data synchronization to N. But it still impractical due to function calling delay. What the speed gap between memory and Ethernet? It could be million times. In single machine, call a function of object is a CPU instruction(most time happen in CPU cache, much faster than memory). In distributed, it is a message pass Ethernet wire. If put business domain object on a machine that share them with others, the app will be very slow let alone your object sharing machine is running in single thread...

Comment: You said WOW is right but it can not prove they CAN do 'single world'. In fact, WOW's single machine can support about 5k players. If reach the max player, you need line up. It absolutely not because xp or something else(most player is in instanced map), for WOW's world, million people in single world indeed is a problem but 7k or 10k does not.

Comment: This is my last post here, if you wish to continue discussing you can email me my site info is in my profile.  I find it funny you keep saying it's impossible to do something I've done professionally several times.  You really think a realm is a single machine?  http://www.gamasutra.com/php-bin/news_index.php?story=25307#.UJvDDMXA9ZY Their production environment in 2009 was 13,000 machines.  Do they have 13k realms?  Go watch the video for that talk I just linked.  Why do you think it's possible to synchronize from client to server but not server to server?  See you in E-Mail maybe.

Comment: Yeah...this discussion is too long. Finally I want to say job can be distributed has restriction: the sub-job split out can not interactive with each other, like SETI@home. If you say highly interactive jobs can be distributed without performance lose, that's not true. Because you create a computation model which can have unlimited computing power which can solve any type problem. BTW, a game server have more than one machine. For WOW, a realm has several machines: world, instance(pve,pvp), database, log, gm, chat, backup, account, even web can be included.

Answer (score 0):

> Break down I/O threads and map threads into DP algorithms.

- Quad/Oct-Trees are good just because they are simple.
- Structure with moving objects (AABB), without having to rebuild a big
  part of the structure for each object
- Depending on the amount of reliable packets you want to send and the
  pace of the RPG TCP should be fine. A lot of networking libraries
  implement TCP basically with UDP allowing reliable/unreliable
  packets.
- Have a deep study on Synchronization architecture of [Croquet
  Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croquet_Project) will help you for better understanding.

Comment: What's the DP algorithms you mention? Dynamic Programming??

Comment: @jean, Yes Dynamic Programming.

Comment: How to do that? DP is method to solve problem which the solution can be accumulate with optimal solution of sub-problem. What's the relation with thread??

Comment: @jean, sorry for any misunderstanding. :) To break down I/O threads and map threads into better tiny/small portions, for example, Qual/Oct-Trees, TCP+UDP where the best, etc. These total words i stated as DP algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I use 2 from your suggested solutions; because my server is c#, this is can be handled very nicely with a lock-less queue of WorkItems which contain a delegate and an array of parameters.

The thread which processes WorkItems can be asleep until a message arrives from the client, or it can always process messages at a update fixed interval. Works very well for me.

Comment: My worried thing is: does this involve delay that can feel by player? For example: player push a key send a attack command to server, when server receive this, it will not handle this immediately. It need wait for next tick of map, then the command will be executed. The largest delay is almost double interval of ticks. Plus network delay (generally less than 200ms), does it OK?