# Is Game Maker capable of creating my MMORPG?

Tags: mmo, game-maker

I have an idea for a turn-based game MMO, and before starting the conception, I need to know if GameMaker is the right program to use. I already took some advice from [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90/why-is-it-so-hard-to-develop-a-mmo/630), and I do not wish to open a discussion or seek an opinion. All I want to know is if it is possible to make my game in GameMaker.

#### My Requirements

1. **The game is an MMORPG.** I have searched and found that *RizenEngine* allows a fully functioning, constantly updating MMO engine for Game Maker.

   - The game needs to be hosted. I can start with one server, with a limited number of players.
   - The game needs to allow for security; not just of the game accounts, but I am already considering cheat prevention and frequent fixes whenever a new exploit is discovered by players.
2. **The game will feature an isometric map.**  A simple 2.5D map is what I intend, if there are functionalities that eases the implementation of tiles for obstacles and back visions.
3. **The game will feature a variety of tactical movements and strategic spell .** I intend to make a turn-based battle system with a movement system and line of sight spell usage.

#### Further Considerations

- The game will be something like [Dofus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eSEb7qS06A) or [Yu Yu Hakusho: Tournament Tactics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnQkmIudbWo) in the playing mode, without having to code from scratch or use old technologies like flash.
- I know it will be hard to make, and may take years, but that is irrelevant to the question.
- I am not asking for alternatives. I only need to know about GameMaker.

Comment: haha. No, It can make only simple games easily and customizing them can be very difficult.

Comment: I'm confused... Your title refers to RPG Maker but the tags & body of your question talk about Game Maker. These are two different tools, so which one are you asking about? Also, it looks like you have multiple questions here — you should edit your post to ask a single question. Then, make a new post if you have a second question. Try to focus on "how do I do this?" (including details of what you've done so far) rather than "is this possible?" if you want meaty, useful answers.

Comment: @DMGregory, I think RPG Maker was the mistake. All other mentions refer to GameMaker, including the reference to the engine the asker already researched for use (RizenEngine), which is for GameMaker.

Comment: I have edited your question to perform a slight overhaul; I agree that the question looked way too broad, because you were asking several questions. By asking the *one* question (is game maker suitable for making my game), and listing the core components of your original set of questions, a good answer will address all of your issues while still answering the core question. Hopefully I have not overshot the mark, but I believe this makes your question far more suitable.

Comment: @Gnemlock thanks for the edit, Its game maker the tool I am asking about

Comment: @DMGregory I know that I have to share an already existing work when I ask questions, but till now I am still at the analysis phase, I can't start with a tool not suitable for my idea, and if someone knows specific plugins for doing this or for doing that, that would be a great answer for my quesiton.

Comment: These all look like questions you could easily research yourself. You already found the RizenEngine, [a simple Google search for Game Maker isometric](https://www.google.ca/search?q=game+maker+isometric&oq=game+maker+isomet&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.4306j0j4&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) turns up plenty of results, and there are likewise plenty of turn-based battle systems present in released Game Maker titles. It looks like you don't need answers here, you just want someone to validate the technology choice you've made. I don't think that's on-topic here.

Comment: the link you just posted is very usefull and it does answer the second question, I am also searching about more plugins that may be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The game is an MMORPG.**

If you're going to be serious about making an MMO with **Gamemaker**, you need to consider you'll be using plugins to handle the networking as **GM:Studio network handling functions** only really work for **WLAN LAN and Mobile**. You'd need to spend a lot of time learning about plugins to handle the networking, In fact you're probably going to need to learn **C++ or Javascript** to write the server code......
In addition to learning **GML**.

> **The game will feature an isometric map.**

A lot of tutorials proves that this can be made by **GameMaker** [see this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvRdVdMjMig&index=2&list=PL7QCJtIssCyM5-Z5EKRGBnAdorhB3P-ix)

> **The game will feature a variety of tactical movements and strategic spell**

Tactical movement and spell use is completely possible with **GameMaker** and probably the easiest of the questions you have asked, although this is still a hard thing to get right in an isometric map.

[This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQ5H9he3-Hs) will be helpfull.

> **Global conclusion**

Yes GameMaker is capable of creating your MMORPG if you use the right plugins.